AWS Kinesis, unknown consumer
Started a job and I inherited a AWS infra, and for most of the services, I can identify their relationship. Documentation is partially there, can see the link between services, but looks like not up to date.
But I'm stuck with Kinesis, there are some streams, where 1 consumer is reading the stream (based on the monitoring, GetRecords operation), but I have no idea who is the consumer! Some of them are easy because Firehose is consuming them.
I have a small idea of what can consume it, but cant find evidence of the setup, also cant find any Lambda trigger linked to them or other services.
Same thing for a producer, I have 1 stream that I have no idea who put records in it.
Producers can be cross account also.
I need to evaluate because most of the service are running but not used, so I would like to get rid of them.
Is there a way to find out who or what is producing or consuming a Kinesis stream?
Started months ago in AWS and still on learning curve, but I think understand many services now.
Thank you
